# Hide Nav Bar and move Table View Section Headers

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6.1

I am currently using the https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar class to hide my nav bar when scrolling, it works great and is extremely simple to use. But I am using it on a table view controller so when I scroll up my section headers don't move and it looks like this.

[image]

How can I move up the section headers to the top of the screen. Or use a different way to move the nav bar when scrolling.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: the problem exists for me too. Hope you would find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first TableViewCell as a custom navigation bar by adding buttons to the contentview contained in the TableViewCell.  It would scroll up like any other TableViewCell.  TableViewCells are mostly just a wrapper for a UIView.  You can modify that UIView like any other UIView.  Every TableViewCell has a property called contentview which is the main UIView in the Cell.

As an example, you could add a button to the first cell that sends the following message 
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

You could call that button "Back"

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView

Comment: is there no way to just move the section headers?

Comment: The section headers should move automatically.  If they are not, your category is breaking UITableViewController.

Comment: This is a very dirty solution and I suggest never to do so like this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this! 

The problem is that, the ***section header*** stays at the `top` value of the `contentInset`. Even though the `navigation bar` is out of view and the `tableView` is visible below, the `contentInset` will remain same.

You would have to modify the library to increase or decrease the `top` value of the `contentInset`, according to the scrolling offset. Try this out and you may post it as a pull request in github.

Hope this helps! :)